# Laravel 4. Russian language as default

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I adjusted app.php as per instruction:

```
'locale' => 'ru',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

But on first visiting the site it **always** shows an english version. Thus russia based user always needs to click "Russian" button to view russian version of the site.(language switching was created with `Session::put('lang', $lang)` and redirect to /).

I also tried using handling session language in `App::before` filter but no luck: it shows in russian all the database content but all that in `trans('message.<word>')` remains in english (the code is now commented in filter.php).

The project is available on [github](https://github.com/rituzy/iblog) (to look through files where you may suspect a reason).

The site address [www.izutov.com](http://www.izutov.com) (there are "English" and "Russian" buttons in the left top corner)
Thnx in advance!

Comment: Which language did you configure in your browser?

Comment: If I go here to chrome settings
    chrome://chrome/settings/languages 
I see Russian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done to set language selection in Laravel 4 :

in app/filters.php

```
App::before(function($request) {

  Route::matched(function($route, $request) {

 if($route->getName() != 'admin') { // don't do it for admin area, (for example)

$language = $_ENV['FALLBACK_LOCALE'];
$lgs = explode(',', $_ENV['LANGUAGES']); // your set of languages

// get the default browser language with the $request object
$browserLg = substr($request->server->get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);

// language set from route (for example /en/some-url)
$requestLg = $request->segment(1);

# if the language called in url request matches your set of languages   
if (null !== $requestLg && in_array($requestLg, $lgs)) {

        $language = $requestLg;            

# default browser lg    
} else { 

    if(in_array($browserLg, $lgs)) {

        $language = $browserLg;
    }
}

// set the validated language
$_ENV['LOCALE'] = $language;
Config::set('locale',$language);
App::setLocale($language);

// share it with views if you want  
View::share('locale', $language);
 });
});
```

Comment: Not clear for me. What is the $request? Where it comes from? This is a part of App::before filter? Could you please show details?

Comment: Thnx @Kyobul, now it's clear. I took the code and revised it a little(there is no need to parse address thus I shortened it a little) And btw needs to add close bracket `);` after `}`